# Will Littering in Private Property be covered under Tort Laws?

Tags: india, tort

Say a person A litters at Private property of person B (maybe his Home) with things that B may find distressful (maybe Cigarette covers or anything similar).

So will person A be legally accountable/liable under "Tort Laws". If not tort law then what else? Does this vary from Country to Country (Assuming all the countries we are talking about have Tort Law)

[I'm new here, anyone reading this, please do edit the tags if necessary]

Thank you.

Findings/Efforts so far: It looks like Littering in public place is covered with a weak penalty.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

Specifically, the tort of [trespass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trespass).

Comment: Any idea on where I may Read up more on Tort of Trespass?